# the potential or hypothetical events which have not yet occurred in the future

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions, case

> We have seen that the basic meaning of the Past tense in English is to
>   locate an event or state in the past. It situate the event at a
>   ‘temporal distance’ from the moment of speaking, whether in time,
>   towards the past, or with regard to potential or hypothetical events
>   which have not yet occurred in the present or the future. (Angela
>   Downing, English Grammar: A University Course)

I don’t have the idea what cases are in the English for ‘the potential or hypothetical events which have not yet occurred in the future.’ Would you let me get the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She perhaps has in mind conditional sentences like *If I wanted some help, I’d ask for it*, where the verb in the *if*-clause is in the past tense.

Comment: Could this also be included in that category: _You'll wish you had never eaten  that_ ?

Comment: @Radu Miron. Yes, except _had never eaten_ is a past perfect construction, rather than past tense.

Comment: The verb in the apodosis is also in the 'past tense'. (This is why I object to attributing 'tense' to verb forms!)

Comment: @StoneyB. I was careful to refer to _past perfect construction_. All professional linguists that I've ever read use _tense_ to describe some verb forms, and most use it to describe only inflected forms, which in English occur only in the present and past tenses.

Comment: I was referring to *I'd ask for it*... I’ve just this evening been reading McCawley, *Syntactic Phenomena in English* (2nd ed., 1998), who argues that “tenses are not merely separate from the verbs that they are attached to but are indeed not even within the [Verb phrases] of which those verbs are the heads”.

Comment: @StoneyB. Oh, right. It depends how he defines 'tense', but this is probably not the place to elaborate.